# Not possible to execute win_ping with Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible

is it possible to give me an hint in regards to Ansible and Windows host? I have set up a Ansible server and a Windows host. I am not able to execute win_ping. It seems that I have something messed up with the configuration on the server.

```
ansible win -m win_ping

Error message:

192.168.178.10 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "the connection plugin 'winrm ## The kind of connection which ansible will make with remote windows node' was not found"
}
```

Firewall config seems to configured properly. I am able to connect from the Ansible server to the Windows host:

```
b@b:~$ nc -vz 192.168.178.10 5986
Connection to 192.168.178.10 5986 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
b@b:~$ nc -vz 192.168.178.10 5985
Connection to 192.168.178.10 5985 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

This is the configuration of /etc/ansible/hosts

```
...
[win]
192.168.178.10

[win:vars]
 ansible_user=a
 ansible_password="xxxx"
 ansible_connection=winrm
 ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
 ansible_port=5986
...
```

Comment: Hi Stefann Deller welcome to SO. As the error message indicates, ansible believes the `connection:` plugin is `winrm ## etc etc` because `#` is only a comment character if preceded by whitespace, it's not like `//` in JS or whatever. You'll want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69658312/edit) and include the playbook, but I'm about 90% certain that's the case. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Ansible uses the pywinrm package to communicate with Windows servers over WinRM. It is not installed by default with the Ansible package, but can be installed by running the following:

```
pip install "pywinrm>=0.3.0"
```

If you have installed the packages required and still facing the issue then I would recommend you to go through Ansible guide again.

```
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html
```